# What assert I should use instead "Assert.DoesNotThrow...."?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I`m following some tutorials about unit testing. The problem is that older versions of xUnit.net provided an "Assert.DoesNotThrow" which now is removed. What I should use instead? 
(in following tutorial this old assert is used)

```
   [Fact]
    public void returns_json_response()
    {
        string results = execute("Batman");

        Assert.Throws.Nothing((new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(results)));
    }
```

Comment: Just do it without assert? If an exception is thrown then the test fails implicitly..

Comment: Assert.DoesNotThrow was pointless/redundant. See this discussion: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/188 (If a tested method is not supposed to be throwing anything, then an exception occuring would make a test fail, so basically Assert.DoesNotThrow would just do what a test would naturally do -- in other words: using Assert.DoesNotThrow was pointless hand-waving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check exceptions with `Record.Exception` method as shown below.

```cs
var exception = Record.Exception(() => new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(results));
Assert.Null(exception);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test the value of 'result`, otherwise you're test is just targeting the JavascriptDeserializer.

If you want to include the serialisation on the dynamic, that's fine, but you should do it by, e.g.;

```
var dynamicFoo = new JavaScriptSerializer( //etc

Assert.Equal("bar", dynamicFoo.Bar);
```

*note* this is not to test the serialized, but to test the `results` string. You could also test the actual string value.